# Can't run R or Rstudio on Mint 18.2

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, linux-mint

I have recently updated from 17 to 18 with a fresh install. I have been trying to make R and Rstudio work, but without success.
R was installed both via terminal based on xenial releases (r-base and r-base-dev) and via the software manager.
I was getting errors due to outdated libraries requests so linked the version I have to the requested one:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52
```

Solved the initial steps but then the problem was the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so: undefined symbol: uloc_setDefault_52
```

Since it keep using "52" I suppose the issue is an outdated library or something alike. But I could not google any results for anything called "uloc" or "libuloc"...
Can anyone help? Thanks!